# A critical error has occurred. Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: dotnetnuke

I was having problems with a skin that I could not uninstall, so I deleted it from the database.

Now my extensions module does not work.

I get this error, "A critical error has occurred. Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Anybody knows what caused it and eventual solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I also had to delete the skin package from the packages table.
The extensions module is working again, but the skin still shows up in admin> skins, and as being in use which is not.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Portals/_default folder for skins directory. It may be installed there and needs to be removed.